# Cannot Enable Wifi. Asus

Tags: wireless, asus

Today I clean installed Ubuntu onto my laptop and when the computer starts up. I notice that I cannot click on the Enable Wifi. I also went into network and tried to turn on wifi there but it still didnt work. It would automatically turn itself back off

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: rfkill lis all Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 the correct command is: `rfkill list` (you forget the 't' in list, also 'all' doesn't seem to be necessary). You can click [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/547651/edit) to change your question. Please open a terminal with Ctrl + Alt + t and enter the command we mentioned, select the result with the mouse and copy it with Ctrl + Shift + c.

Comment: Quite correct! Sorry for my typo. rfkill list all Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be missing the firmware for your wifi network card.

Try to download it and reboot (check here http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi and put the firmware in /lib/firmware)

Comment: Why do you believe he has an Intel wireless card? Moreover, most Intel firmware is included by default.